# Existence of a "three-point" machine learning model?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, algorithms, multilabel-classification, model-selection

I may want to ask if there are studies that exist which utilize a **"three-point machine learning model**. What I mean by "three-point machine learning model is that **it may use several algorithms in order to construct a model (in this case, it would be three machine learning algorithms)**.

An example would be coming from our study which utilizes **Random Forest (RF)**, **Gaussian Mixture Model (GMM)**, and **Radial Basis Function (RBF) Neural Network** *in order to construct a machine learning model within the context of multi-label classification*.

I may just want to ask also if a "three-point approach" is a feasible way to construct machine learning models like what we have in mind?

Comment: Are you asking about *stacking*?

Comment: not exactly stacking, but utilizing several algorithms to build a model (for example, the process of the model involves feeding data to RF algorithm for dimensionality reduction, then the outcome value of it would be then fed to GMM for feature learning, the outcome value of it is then finally fed to RBFNN for classification.

Comment: Yes, it is very common to apply different algorithms on each stage and chain them together. In fact, hardly any production system does not do this.

Comment: Depending on how the models are chained, it may be called a pipeline (e.g. your example), or stacking (bagging, boosting) etc..

Comment: You may find a lot of examples in [sklearn's doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#examples-using-sklearn-pipeline-pipeline).

Comment: I see I see, so basically the main process that we got from our study is indeed considered a "PIPELINE." Thus, we have Machine Learning Pipeline (MLP) We also noticed that the aspect of chaining algorithms is still applied in machine learning and is quite interesting.

We will take note of these info you have provided for us, and we will explore the sklearn docs that you have sent here. Thank you very much @lpounng